# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Articles#show in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got the error as

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments.article_id: SELECT
>   "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."article_id" = ?

And code is

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
<p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

    <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
</p>
<% end %>

<!-- <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <% end %> -->

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %>
```

Comment: Do you have `article_id` in `comments` table?

Comment: And also post the `full error stack`.

Comment: make sure you've run all your migrations as wel.

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of options to raise this error please check the following:

1. in you comment class you have field `article_id` and also you should have in Article model.

   > class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   >
   > ```
   >     has_many :comments
   > ```
   >
   > end
   >
   > class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   >
   > ```
   >     belongs_to :article
   > ```
   >
   > end
2. make sure you have did `rake db:migrate` after creating all the models.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're following the official tutorials, redo the step for creating comment migration might will help you:

create the Comment class:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

update the migration file for comments (be sure you have the references field):

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :comments do |t|
       t.string :commenter
       t.text :body
       t.references :article, index: true, foreign_key: true

       t.timestamps null: false
     end
   end
 end
```

Please notice that t.references is important, rails will create the missing article_id on comments only if you have the references there.

After this, you can run migrate again, and run rollback if necessary:

```
rails db:rollback
rails db:migrate
```

You should have the article_id now.